# Change CSS style of an element after user click on an area of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

The area is defined by using map tag. There is also a paragraph above the image. When the user click on the image area, the color of the paragraph will change. Any idea how to do this with javascript?

For example, this is the html

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>The map and area elements</h1>

<p>Click on the area of the image, there will be several areas. When click, the color will change depending on the area that was clicked.</p>

<img src="theimage.jpg" alt="image" usemap="#theimage" width="400" height="379">

<map name="theimage">
  <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="thearea" href="">
</map>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the style of the `<p>` tag when you click on the area with the coordinates of the `<area>` tag, use the usual `addEventListener` event listener for the *click* event.

Also, you need to make a delegation to prevent the default behavior when clicking on tag `<area>` using `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
let paragraph = document.querySelector("p");
let area = document.querySelector("area");

area.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    paragraph.style.color = "green";
});
```

```html
<h1>The map and area elements</h1>
<p>Click on the area of the image, there will be several areas. When click, the color will change depending on the area that was clicked.</p>
<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1428083/2946/i/600/depositphotos_29460297-stock-photo-bird-cage.jpg" alt="image" usemap="#theimage" width="400" height="379" />
<map name="theimage">
    <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="thearea" href="" />
</map>
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I wish I could give you an upvote but I dont have enough reputation lol. Thanks so much

Comment: @Minhkhuepham, no problem

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code this will work fine**

```js
window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
    let my_image=document.querySelector('.my-image');
    let para=document.querySelector('p');
    my_image.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        para.style.color='blue';
    })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Tutorial</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>The map and area elements</h1>

    <p>Click on the area of the image, there will be several areas. When click, the color will change depending on the area that was clicked.</p>
    <img
      src="theimage.jpg"
      alt="Workplace"
      usemap="#workmap"
      width="400"
      height="379"
    />

    <map name="workmap">
      <area
        shape="rect"
        coords="34,44,270,350"
        alt="Computer"
        class="my-image"
      />
      
    </map>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note : Don't add href attribute in area tag even by mistake because your paragraph color will change but page will get also refresh ,If the once  page refresh then there will not be any benefit of color change.